# Is there a way for content assist to allow wildcard characters in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

This is not the first time that I would have needed that... 
 In the example bellow I would love to have all set*Listeners listed so I wouldn't have to scroll trough all the houndreds of methods to find the listener setter I need.

[image: eclipse camelCase content assist]

Is there a way to do that, or any alternative that lets me search trough the content assist results more effectively? (Allowing a wildcard character would be a really good start)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Eclipse Code Recommenders](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders) project includes [subwords completion](http://eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/#subwords-completion) which seems to be what you are looking for. In your example, it will find *setListener* when completing on *sLis*. You don't even have to type in a wildcard.

Keep in mind that subwords completion is not activated by default. Go to *Preferences > Code Recommenders > Completions* and activate the *Subwords-Completion Processor*.

Comment: perfect! this should be enabled by default! so long suffering... because I didnt think it was possible, until today I put the question and fortunately you had the answer, thx! :D

Comment: I just thought also, this option could be a check box in the very completion popup, what a relief!!!